# Use BoundedVec in benchmark

Tags: benchmarking, benchmark, boundedvec

I have some code that benchmarks one of my extrinsic.

```
benchmarks! {
    create_supersig {
        let z in 0 .. 10;

        let alice: T::AccountId = get_account::<T>("ALICE");
        let bob: T::AccountId = get_account::<T>("BOB");
        let charlie: T::AccountId = get_account::<T>("CHARLIE");
        let val: BalanceOf<T> = 4_000_000_000u32.into();
        T::Currency::make_free_balance_be(&alice, val.saturating_mul(4_000_000_000u32.into()));

        let mut vec_members = vec!{(alice.clone(), Role::Standard), (bob, Role::Standard), (charlie, Role::Standard)};
        let oui = "oui";
        for i in 0 .. z {
            let acc = benchmark_account(oui, i, 0);
            vec_members.push((acc, Role::Standard));
        }
        let members: BoundedVec<_, _> = vec_members.try_into().unwrap();
    }: _(RawOrigin::Signed(alice.clone()), members.clone())
    verify {
        assert_eq!(Pallet::<T>::nonce_supersig(), 1);
    }
}
```

`members` is a bounded `Vec` of the members of the organization I'm creating.
The code (and other variations I tried) panic when I try to build the `BoundedVec`, at:

```
        let members: BoundedVec<_, _> = vec_members.try_into().unwrap();
```

If I remove the loop filling the `Vec`, which means that the bounded `Vec` will always be the same length (aka the same type), it doesn't panic anymore.

Is it because:

- I'm not using `BoundedVec` the right way
- I cannot use `BoundedVec` like this in benchmarks (probably due to the work done by the macro)

What should I do?

1. change the type expected by my extrinsic from `BoundedVec` to `Vec` ?
2. find a way to specify the size/type of my `BoundedVec` in the benchmarks

It's defined in my pallet config:

```
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
            ...
        /// The maximum number of account that can added or removed in a single call
        #[pallet::constant]
        type MaxAccountsPerTransaction: Get<u32>;
    }
```

And use in the extrinsic signature:

```
        #[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::create_supersig(members.len() as u32))]
        pub fn create_supersig(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            members: BoundedVec<(T::AccountId, Role), T::MaxAccountsPerTransaction>,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `BoundedVec` anywhere.

What is the value of `MaxAccountsPerTransaction` you used in the mock runtime?

If `z + 3 > MaxAccountsPerTransaction`, then you got this error.